# Creating a Nearest function programmatically

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I've been trying to work out how to create a `Nearest` function programmatically. My goal is to produce something similar to this, a hand-assembled function:

```
nf = Nearest[{0.0 -> "B", 0.05 -> "W", 0.1 -> "H", 0.15 -> "h", 
    0.2 -> "e", 0.3 -> "c",  0.4 -> "o", 0.5 -> "'", 0.6 -> "-", 
    0.7 -> ":", 0.8 -> ".", 0.9 -> "-", 0.95 -> " "}];
```

But instead of making it by hand, and editing the values, I want to pass a string and get all the letters allocated automatically to values between 0 and 1. (This is for producing ASCII-art type versions of images.)

For example, a function that looks a bit like this:

```
makeNearestFunction[string_] :=
 nf = Nearest[
  Riffle[
   Range[0, 1, N[1/StringLength[string]]], Characters[string]]
   ...
   (* returns a nearest function *)
```

could be called like this:

```
nf = makeNearestFunction["Mathematica!:- "]
```

I've got as far as producing a list of data like this:

```
{0., "M", 0.0666667, "a", 0.133333, "t", 0.2, "h", 0.266667, "e", 
 0.333333, "m", 0.4, "a", 0.466667, "t", 0.533333, "i", 0.6, "c", 
 0.666667, "a", 0.733333, "!", 0.8, ":", 0.866667, "-", 0.933333, " ", 
 1.}
```

but the pairs need to be assembled as rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The threading shown in my original answer below is unnecessary as `Nearest` accepts this form:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore you may use:

```
makeNearestFunction[string_] := 
  Nearest[Rescale@Range@Length@# -> #] & @ Characters@string
```

---

Perhaps this?

```
makeNearestFunction[string_] :=
 MapThread[Rule,
   {
    Most @ Range[0, 1, N[1 / StringLength@string]],
    Characters @ string
   }
 ] // Nearest
```

Or this?

```
makeNearestFunction[string_] :=
  With[{len = StringLength @ string},
    Nearest @ Thread[Range[0`, len - 1]/len -> Characters @ string]
  ]
```

This doesn't include `1.` in the function, but neither does your hand-assembled function.

Comment: You make it look easy! :) I couldn't work out how to use the `Rule` function, but I see that it isn't essential. Nice one, sir!

Comment: @cormullion Thanks.  I'm not sure which numeric value you want the last character to map to: `1` or one increment before `1`, e.g. `0.95`/`0.933`.  What is your intent?

Comment: The 1.0 value will correspond to pure white in the original image, so it will occur rarely anyway. Or, in other words, I don't yet know... :)

Answer (score 4):

```
makeNearestFunc1[string_String] := Nearest[Rule @@@ 
     Transpose@{Rescale@Range@StringLength@#, Characters@#}&@string]
```

or, a slight variation of Mr.W's second function,

```
makeNearestFunc2[string_String] :=
   Nearest@Thread[Rescale@Range@StringLength@# -> Characters@#] &@string
```

EDIT: To change the range to which the characters are mapped, use

```
Rescale[Range@#, {1, #}, {0, (-1 + #)/#}] &@StringLength@#
```

instead of

```
Rescale@Range@StringLength@#
```